# Bootstrap carousel and show display different text accordingly to current slide with text animations

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to display text on my background image with text animations. When the slider changes new text should appear with new animation. How can I achieve that in bootstrap ?

Comment: https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-css3-animations/  - refer this

Comment: thanks @SoumyaB.Athani

Comment: show us what exactly do you want

Comment: text witjh new animation  what do you mean????? when it slides the text changes that ok but what do yoiu mean by text animation changes???

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .m1{
      color: red;
    }
    .m2{
      color:blueviolet;
    }
    .m3{
      color:chartreuse;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <!-- Indicators -->
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>

      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="item active">
          <img src="1.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="m1">Los Angeles</h3>
            <p class="m1">LA is always so much fun!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="2.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="m2">Chicago</h3>
            <p class="m2">Thank you, Chicago!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
          <img src="3.jpg" alt="New York" style="width:100%;">
          <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3 class="m3">New York</h3>
            <p class="m3">We love the Big Apple!</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Left and right controls -->
      <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

you can check the fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/bfg2e0L3/

Comment: @ravanone you can upvote it and give it a green tick  on the left side of the question